# Comment/uncomment a block of code in NetBeans shortcut

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there a shortcut in NetBeans to highlight a block of code and comment/uncomment it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The list of keyboard shortcuts can be found in the [NetBeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/KeymapProfileFor60).

**Turn On/Off Search Result highlights**

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

**Add/remove comment. Should work for all languages**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> **or in mac** <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Can't get Ctrl + / to work on a swedish keyboard, worked with Girish answer.

Comment: netbeans only comments by line `//`. How can you do block comments? `/*  */`

Answer (score 111):

Try this combination in the Netbeans Editor: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: or else ctrl + /

Answer (score 8):

An IDE independent trick (that works for all languages in the C/Java/C++/C# family) I found to comment/uncomment blocks of code fast is the following:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
//*
if(a < b) {
    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
//*/
System.out.println("a: "+a);
```

Say you want to comment and uncomment the `if` block frequently. You can use the `//*` and `//*/` markers. You comment the block by removing one `/` in the `//*` part. Thus:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
/*
if(a < b) {
    int t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
//*/
System.out.println("a: "+a);
```

**Why this works**

In case the first line reads `//*`, it is interpreted as `// *`, thus you comment the `*` and don't comment the remainder of the block. The `//*/` is ignored as well since it is interpreted as `// */`.

In case the first line reads `/*`, it is interpreted as the start of a comment block. Java searches for the corresponding end which is `// */` (the `//` is ignored).

Comment: I use a similar trick for switching between two chunks of code. `/**/` at the start, `/*/` between the two chunks, and `/**/` at the end.  Simply remove or re-add one of the asterisks from the first comment to switch between blocks.

Answer (score 1):

In mac, it is more stable to use command+shift+c. Sometimes, command+/ could be usable but not so stable.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to have a whole block commented, can be useful the rectangular selection trick as a single "null column" rectangle where we can add any comment character we like (eg. an hash or a slash):

[image]

The shortcut in Mac is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549692/editing-multiple-lines-of-code-in-netbeans).

To return to the normal selection just repeat the same shortcut.

Comment: you type multiple lines with this shortcut but its very useful