# Editing multiple lines of code in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, editing

Is there a way to select and edit multiple rows of code in netbeans?
Visual Studio allows a similar operation where you press <kbd>alt</kbd> and select multiple lines using the dragging motion (left click) of mouse ?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://superuser.com

Comment: I disagree, I am pretty active on super user and its not really the right place for this question. It lies in a bit of grey area and stackoverflow suits the purpose better.
for e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460945/how-to-multiple-line-editing-in-eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, it is a programming tool, which is why I didn't vote to close or downvote.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's called **rectangular selection**.
It can be enabled by <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

[Screenshots for steps](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/rectangular_selection):

> ## Rectangular Selection
>
> By Petr on Oct 20, 2011
>
> If you use development build, you probably noticed that NetBeans
>   editor added **Rectangular Selection** action. I don't need this
>   functionality every day, but it can be helpful in some case. One of
>   such case is when you need to delete line numbers in a text  or code
>   copied from  a tutorial. Like on the picture below.
>
> [image: sample code]
>
> You can select the rectangle after pressing Rectangular Selection
>   toggle button in the editor toolbar or pressing
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut.
>
> [image: Rectangular Selection toggle button]
>
> The selection can be easily done with mouse or keyboard. When you use
>   keyboard, just place the caret on a corner, keep down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
>   and with the arrows keys you select what you need.
>
> [image: keep down SHIFT and with the arrows keys you select what you need]
>
> When the selection is done, you can easily delete all the line numbers
>   with pressing <kbd>DELETE</kbd> key. Then you have to exit from the
>   rectangle selection mode
>   (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or toggle button in the
>   editor toolbar).
>
> If you write a text , then the text is placed on every line in the
>   selected area. This can be useful for example for changing access
>   modifiers of more fields in a class at once.
>
> [image: If you write a text , then the text is placed on every line in the selected area]

Comment: Is it possible to place the cursor in different locations? i. e. in the first word, in the second word of second line and third word from third line.

Comment: I don't think so, it selects by columns in the page, so if the three words in the three rows start from the same column you can do it

Comment: its possible to place independent cursors with ctrl+shift+left-click - at least in the latest builds

Comment: There is a new way. It works exactly like in Sublime. See my answer.

Answer (score 46):

A more flexible alternative to the Rectangular Selection has now been incorporated in Netbeans 8.2, which supports multiple cursors.

[image: Demonstration of multiple carets]

Keyboard shortcuts are listed on the [Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB82#Editor_Multicarets):

```
Description                      Windows/Linux      Mac
==============================   ================   ================
Add/remove caret                 Ctrl+Shift+Click   Cmd+Shift+Click 
Add caret for next occurence     Ctrl+J             Cmd+J   
Add caret for each occurrence    Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J   Ctrl+Cmd+Shift+J    
Add caret on line above          Alt+Shift+[        Ctrl+Shift+[ or
                                                     Alt+Cmd+Up
Add caret on line below          Alt+Shift+]        Ctrl+Shift+] or
                                                     Alt+Cmd+Down   
Remove last added caret          Alt+Shift+J        Ctrl+Shift+J    
Paste over the multiple carets   Ctrl+Shift+L       Cmd+Shift+L or
                                                     Alt+Cmd+V  
Remove all extra carets          Escape             Escape
```

Answer (score 12):

### After Netbeans 8.2 release

Since Netbeans 8.2 this functionality is available out of the box. Just press `Shift + Ctrl` and hold it down, now left click your mouse anywhere as many times as you need to.

NetBeans Development version allows you to edit multiple lines like in Sublime Text.

Don't bother to read the answer below. You don't need to download Development release any longer.

### Before Netbeans 8.2 release

Yes you can! Works exactly as in SublimeText but it is not default feature so You will have to download NetBeans development build.

[image]

After installation press `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `Alt` now `left click` anywhere in the code while holding Shift + Ctrl + Alt. Easy and very useful.

This is how it looks like in NetBeans:

[image]

See video presentation at: [youtube.com/watch?v=iWejyPL5YQI](http://youtube.com/watch?v=iWejyPL5YQI)

When you install new NetBeans you don't have to uninstall the old one. Just leave it be. Development build will ask you if you want to import all the plugins and presets you where using in your previous NetBeans installation.

Comment: In Ubuntu (GNU/Linux) I found that the shortcut is Shift+Ctrl, and that the Alt stops it working.

Comment: Some here in another distro. But I don't think it's an OS thing. 
It's just Shift + Ctrl, not Alt. See ms609 answer for more.

Comment: Yeah, Shift+Ctrl on Win 7 too

Comment: On windows 10 with NetBeans 8.2 (updated 6.10.2017) works this: hold down Shift+Ctrl and click on places where you want to have your cursors -> just like in sublime text, works prefectly!

Answer (score 5):

From [Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB82#Editor_Multicarets): *Add/Remove caret and enter multi-caret mode*

### Shortcut Windows/Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click

### Shortcut Mac:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click

Answer (score 4):

In netbeans 8.2 on Linux the hotkey is `shift + ctrl` and holding left button's mouse. From my own experience. It is easy ascertainable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bit different for previous versions of Netbeans and different OS's. For my part, for Netbeans 8.2 on Windows 10, holding down `Shift + Ctrl` and left clicking works.