# Uncomment a block of code in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

from this link http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic21825.html
The code is:

```
cut-to-clipboard "/*" paste-from-clipboard "*/"
```

And assigned it the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
It works.

But i tried a lot to write a macro to uncomment the block of code

(Will remove block comment i.e /* ...*/).

But it did not work. how can i write the macro?

Comment: What is your end game? 

Are you trying to learn how to write a macro or you want to have a shortcut to comment/uncomment a codeblock in netbeans?

If it's the latter this post [Comment/Uncomment Code Block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010360/comment-and-uncomment-a-block-of-code) already provides the netbeans shortcut that does that.

Answer (score 0):

In [FAQEditorMacros](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorMacros) you have 2 options:

```
toggle-comment   Toggle Comment
uncomment        Uncomment
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a find and replace tool, like in Dreamweaver you'll be able to use a "replace all" option.